# Getting CSS values from an element inside an array loop causes an error in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get the CSS values from each children, do some calculations and then apply it back to each child.

When trying to assign the left CSS value into a variable called X using jQuery i get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Code on how I do it

```
const wayps = document.querySelector('#waypoints');
const children = wayps.childNodes;
var x,y,canvas_x,canvas_y,px_x,px_y;
children.forEach(function(wayps) {
   
    x = $(wayps).css("left");

});
```

But applying CSS to each element within the array works with no errors.

```
   children.forEach(function(wayps) {
        console.log(wayps.innerText); 
// or
       $(wayps).css("left" , 0+"px");
});
```

Complete code

```
const wayps = document.querySelector('#waypoints');
const children = wayps.childNodes;
var x,y,canvas_x,canvas_y,px_x,px_y;
children.forEach(function(wayps) {
   
    x = $(wayps).css("left");
    x = x/2;
    $(wayps).css("left" , x+"px");

});
```

HTML as requested

```
<div id="main">
        <div id="map">
  
        <div id="map_">
        <div id="waypoints">
                <div id="waypoint" class="waypoint_17" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>   
                <div id="waypoint" class="waypoint_18" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="frm">
    </div>
    </div>
```

How do you solve this problem?

Comment: Post please  your `HTML` too and why do you use `forEach` with `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. First, I replaced the id with a class like so:

```
 <div id="waypoint" class="waypoint_17" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
```

with

```
  <div class="waypoint" id="waypoint_17" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
```

Then i used querySelectorAll instead querySelector

```
document.querySelectorAll('.waypoint');
```

And finally, to do the calculation, the right way to get the left value is to convert it to an integer by doing so

```
 x = parseInt($(wayps).css('left'));
```

And finally the working code

```
  var  waypsList = document.querySelectorAll('.waypoint'); 
    [].forEach.call(waypsList, function(wayps) {
       
        x = parseInt($(wayps).css('left'));
        x = x/2;
        $(wayps).css("left" , x+"px");

});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).